# Adding portMappings to Dockerrun.aws.json with Single container configuartion

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using **ElasticBeanstalk with single docker container**. I am using DataDog(statsd client) for pushing metrics from the docker container. I have a running datadog-agent which is technically a statsd client on the host machine. The issue I am facing is to connect that client running at port 8125 from the container.

What I have tried is:

1. `EXPOSE PORT 8125/udp` in Dockerfile which obviously didn't work.
2. Added Dockerrun.aws.json with

   ```
   {
     "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
     "portMappings": [
       {
         "hostPort": 8125,
         "containerPort": 8125
      }
    ]
   }
   ```

   But the issue is portMappings seems to added in V2 which is not available for single docker container.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
{
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
    "Ports": [
        {
            "ContainerPort": "8125"
        }
    ]
}
```